# Sort and take 1 children in EF 4.1

Tags: sorting, entity-framework-4.1, children

I found this blog about my problem

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/02/25/tip-1-sorting-relationships-in-entity-framework.aspx

But its from 2009 and not for 4.1

My problem is this..

I have a List of Customer, which have a list of ReconciliationDate
i only want to take 1 ReconciliationDate but it has to be the one with the highest date...

I could do it like the blog says and project my result on a anonymous type and then after the question been executed against SQL I can itterate over the result in memory and set the ReconciliationDate from the anonymous back on the Customer. But that feels like an ugly hack..

Are there better ways of doing this in 4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no better way. Relations cannot be sorted or filtered without projection and you cannot project to mapped types so you need either anonymous or another non mapped type.